# Flask audit log in separate file

Tags: python, logging, flask

I'm having a bit of trouble grasping how python does its logging and how to set them up to achieve what I'm looking for.

What I'd like to have is in addtion to my regular flask log thats logging app errors, info, api calls etc is to have a separate custom log that only logs very specific events that aren't necessarily tied to a level like info or warning they're just messages so what I have currently is this.

```
# My flask set up
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('upload_service.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
    '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
))
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

This handles my normal logging and then where I need custom logging I've been putting this in my class

```
logger = logging.getLogger('audit')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('audit.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
    '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
))
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

And for my logging I just do

```
logger.info("You changed something %s", request.headers["X-FORWARDED-FOR"])
```

This just lets me separate out my logging and not have my audit file polluted with any of the regular flask logging. For now this works OK but I see there is a lot of stuff that can be done using filters and stuff with flask in order to automatically log things like the IP address, username and stuff like here http://roryokeeffe.com/production-logging-in-flask-python/ instead of having to manually do it like how I am now

I'd like to do something like this.

```
# My flask set up
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('upload_service.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
    '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
))
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

audit_handler = RotatingFileHandler('audit.log')
audit_handler .setFormatter(Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(ip) %(message)s '
    '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
))
audit_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
app.logger.addHandler(audit_handler)
context_provider = ContextualFilter()
app.logger.addFilter(context_provider)
```

And In my code I'd like to be able to capture events only into a specific log somehow.

```
current_app.logger.info("This is a regular log")
# Can I get a particular handler here ?
current_app.logger.handlers["audit"].info("This is a special log file")
```

Does anyone have any strategies for approaching something like this or changes to my logging config? I've been scanning the python logging documentation for about a day now and it's just not getting any clearer how to handle this.

Comment: As I understood, you have specific routes/endpoints in `Flask` which must use additional logger handlers? For example, `/index` - default logger handler, `/order` - additional handlers.

Comment: Close. That would probably get me on the right track. What i'd like is basically an additional log handler that I write to explicitly. Maybe I'm going about it wrong calling it a 'handler'. I just want something I can share across routes that logs certain data separately from the normal logging.

Comment: could you add an example with routes how it should works?